# Is this Dockerfile extending a image or creating a new one ?

Tags: docker

I was just going through this tutorail **[HERE](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/)** about Docker images and to be more specific , it was about extending a docker image, now if you scroll to the section that says: **Building an image from a Dockerfile** , you'll see that a new Dockerfile is being built , now is this a independent image or is this Dockerfile extending the `training/sinatra` image ?? That would be by question.

So to repeat my question , is the Dockerfile in the **Building an image from a Dockerfile** section, creating a new image or extending the `training/sinatra` image ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command in that section is

```
docker build -t ouruser/sinatra:v2
```

That means it is creating a new image, extending the one mentioned in the Dockerfile: `FROM ubuntu:14.04`

The end result is:

> a new image belonging to the user `ouruser`, the repository name `sinatra` and given it the tag `v2`.
>
> each step creates a new container, runs the instruction inside that container and then commits that change - just like the `docker commit` work flow we saw earlier.
> When all the instructions have executed we’re left with the `97feabe5d2ed` image (also helpfully tagged as `ouruser/sinatra:v2`) and all intermediate containers will get removed to clean things up.

So again, this is an independent image, independent from `training/sinatra`.

To extends an image, you

- either make a Dockerfile which starts "`FROM <animage>`", and build it: it will execute a series of `docker commit` on each intermediate containers.
- or, and that is what is described in "[Updating and committing an image](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#updating-and-committing-an-image)", you do that manually, by running a bash, executing an order, exiting and committing the exited container into a new image.

The first approach scales better: you chain multiple commits specified in one Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for the details answer , in the `Updating and committing an image` section i beleive though the image is being extended right ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik a manual extension, yes. I have edited the answer to detail that.